# Approximation in non-compact interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function defined on a interval $I\subseteq \Bbb R$.

(a) If $I=[0,1]$ and $\epsilon \gt0$ is given show that there are finitely many constants $a_k$, $1\le k \le n$, so that

$|f(x)-\sum^n_{k=1} a_ke^{-kx}|\lt \epsilon$  for all $x\in I$

(b) show that the statement in Part (a) is false if the interval $I$ is $I=[0,\infty )$

(c) suppose that $f$ is contiuous on $I=[ 0,\infty )$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0.$ Is the conclusion in Part (a) true for suchh $f?$

For the Proof of (a) just we have show Span{$e^{-kx}$} is dense in the space so by Stone -Weierstrass we will be done.

For the proof of (b) just we take $f(x)=x$ we will see the contradiction.

But i am little confused about (c), it seems true but i don't know how to show. Please can you show me part (c).
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the limit is 0, then you can take a compact subinterval $[0,N]$ where $N$ is so large that $0<|f|<\epsilon/2$ and use Stone-Weierstraß there, then on the compact interval the finite sums are within $\epsilon$ by assumption and on the tail the finite sums go to 0, in particular you can choose $N$ large enough so that for $x>N$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n|a_ke^{-kx}|<{\epsilon\over 2}$$

so that

$$\left|f-\sum_{k=1}^na_ke^{-kx}\right|<{\epsilon\over 2}+{\epsilon\over 2}=\epsilon$$

Comment: This isn't totally correct in this form: you choose $N$, and then the $a_k$'s and $n$ depending on $N$ (and $\epsilon$), and then you change $N$ again, depending on the $a_k$'s, so this is circular. It should be easy to fix, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's lazy writing on my part, I'll fix it.

Comment: On second thoughts, it might actually be not that straightforward...

Comment: There's a version of SW that gives the conclusion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: That's the version I was thinking of. The basic idea really isn't **that** far removed, it's just got some mild complications.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to prove (c) is first to show an extended version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem: If your algebra of continuous functions on the compact set $X$ separates points and vanishes at the point $x_0$, but at no other point of $X$, then the uniform closure consists of all continuous functions $f$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.

Then use this result on the one-point-compactification of the real line, where $x_0$ is the point at infinity.